# react setState interval

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm using `setState()` to update a badge displaying the number of unread messages a user has:

```
updateUnread(){
  this.setState({
    unreadCount: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  });
}

render(){
  setInterval(() => this.updateUnread(), 2000);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Messages unreadCount={this.state.unreadCount} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, it keeps flickering between the numbers, as you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/BlW831h1IFo). I'm not sure why this is, as I'm pretty new to React, but I think it might be that a new interval is being created every time it updates. If this is the case, how am I supposed to do this?

And yes, I know it's just random numbers being put in there, this is only development :)

Comment: I found a solution too. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the interval in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and make sure you do **NOT** update the state directly via the render method.

Updating the state via the `render` method is a bad-practice. It can lead to poor performance and infinity loop too.

The problem in your case is that on each rerender, you set a new interval that will lead to infinity.

**Here's how you can do it:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => this.updateUnread(), 2000);
  this.setState({ intervalId })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   // Make sure to clear the interval, on unmount
   clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
}

updateUnread(){
  this.setState({
    unreadCount: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  });
}

render(){

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <Messages unreadCount={this.state.unreadCount} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please keep in mind that it's a bad-practice and you should not update your component's state via the `render` method directly.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan now you can consider accepting it, if the answer still working for you! :D :)